# Newline in SQLite text cell

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic app with a SQLite Database pre-filled with SQLiteBrowser.
I can't find a way to have a new line in a text cell...

I tried with `<br/>` but it doesn't work.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, simply put the newline into the string:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(TextColumn) VALUES ('first line
second line');
```

When the text value is constructed in another programming language, use whatever method that language uses:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO MyTable(TextColumn) VALUES (?)";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["first line\nsecond line"]);
```